# For each output of grep execute multiple commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, grep, awk

**First**:

```
sudo netstat -nptc | grep -oP "\K[0-9]*(?=/perl)"
```

The above gives me the pid as they are started, so it is constantly running.

**Second**:

For each output of the first command above I want to execute below:

```
ps aux | grep <output of first>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

To send the output of one command into the command line of another command use `xargs`.

The complication here is that you need to start a pipeline, and for that use a shell.  That can be done with something like:

```
sudo netstat -nptc | grep -oP "\K[0-9]*(?=/perl)" | xargs -l sh -c 'ps aux | grep "$0"'
```

([Reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106294/208146))

Comment: I tried your solution but didn't work, it doesn't return anything, this part works sudo netstat -nptc | grep -oP "\K[0-9]*(?=/perl)" but the next part returns nothing.